# Is this proof of a theorem on subsequence convergence correct?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, proof-writing

I'm taking my first course on analysis. I came across this theorem and I wonder whether this proof that I have written is correct. In case it is incorrect, please point out the mistakes I have made.

Here is the written proof:

[image]

Comment: What is k in the second to last line (for all n greater than k...)? Also, can you explain the definition of S'? The notation is a bit confusing.

Comment: @FélixMorenoPeñarrubia k is a natural number. Perhaps that and S' would be better understood if we follow the definition of a subsequence. I've used exactly the definition but in terms of a set because, personally, I find the concept of subsequences much easier to grasp in those terms.

Comment: I meant to ask what does k represent. You use a variable named "k" in the previous line when you state the definition of convergence of a subsequence, but I see no relationship with the "for all n greater than k" statement in the second-to-last line. I can't understand either what roles do the sets S and S' play in that step. I would recommend to rewrite and clarify the second part of the proof, as it is currently not understandable.

Comment: Well, let's see, X', the subsequence of X, is also a sequence and will thus have the same definition of convergence as sequences. Now, in that definition, we talk about the terms of (x¬n) after a certain m (we say "for all n ≥ m”). Similarly for subsequence X', the definition would hold for all nk ≥ m, which is similar to saying k ≥ m, because we know nk ≥ k for all k.

Comment: As for the set notation, as I said, it helps ME, especially in being convinced about making the ‘transition’ from xnk to xn(which we can do because as S' is a subset of S, so xnk belongs to X and is also of the form xn), that we make in the second last line of the proof. 

As for the problem you have with n ≥ k, this comes because I want to say n ≥ m, and since k ≥ m, n ≥ k works just fine.

Comment: If you are only using the information that one arbitrary subsequence converges, then your proof cannot possibly be right since it is not true that the convergence of a subsequence implies the convergence of the complete sequence. It is still not completely clear to me what are you trying to do with the sets: it looks like you are saying that the convergence condition holding for a particular subset of the indices implies it holds for all (sufficiently large) indices, which doesn't make much sense (but again, if you are only using an arbitrary subsequence, you can't prove the theorem)